# Why can I not use strcpy() with strtok() in the following way

Tags: c, string

I am a new C programmer and so you will have to excuse my lack of knowledge. Slowly but surely I am improving. I am wondering why I cannot use the following code to try and remove the '/n' that fgets introduces when grabbing user input. It breaks after the first print statement. I feel as though I am doing something dangerous but I am not sure what.

```
if (fgets(rawCommand, sizeof (rawCommand), stdin)) {

    printf( "\nTest: %s\n", rawCommand ); //test print
    strcpy( rawCommand, strtok( rawCommand, '\n') ); //to get rid of the '\n' that fgets introduces
    rawCommand[ strlen(rawCommand) - 1 ] = '\0';
    printf( "\nTest: %s\n", rawCommand ); //test print
```

All advice is appreciated but please keep it constructive. Thanks.

Comment: 1. There is no guarantee the line returned by `fgets()` terminates with a newline. 2. `strcpy` is not the way to do that regardless. just look for the newline at the end of the string, and **if found**, set to 0. `strcpy()` on an overlapping buffer invokes *undefined behavior*. And good job checking that `fgets()` didn't return NULL. you'd be surprised now many people ignore that.

Comment: and should be `strtok(rawCommand, "\n"),` second parametaer needs `char*`, not `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most of the code correct. But the neither the `strcpy()` nor the `strtok()` are needed. To throw out the *potentially* trailing newline consider this:

```
size_t len = strlen(rawCommand);
if (len && rawCommand[len-1] == '\n')
    rawCommand[len-1] = 0;
```

and as I said in comment. good job checking for NULL returned form `fgets()`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense in terms of removing the possible '/n'. I knew there was something fishy about what I was trying.

Comment: Another quick question is 0 the same as '/0'? Does 0 also work as a string terminator?

Comment: Meant '\0' - my mistake

Comment: @TheCount It works. It also prevents you from having to find all the places in your code where you used `'\0'` when porting to Unicode, where the literal would be `L'\0'` By using `0` you get the conversion to the right thing for free. Its a habit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will try and make that my habit as well.